# App shows two accessibility services even though only one is registered in manifest

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I have an app that registers an accessibility service in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
<service android:name="com.package.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="@bool/is_lollipop_and_above"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>
```

My `accessibilityservice.xml` looks like this:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_description"/>
```

This works fine, but when I go to Android accessibility settings, I see two versions of my app's service:

[image]

The first one does not have any description and turning it on/off does not seem to affect the way my app behaves at all.

If I disable the service by commenting it out of my manifest file, the descriptionless service still sticks around:

[image]

I'm not sure what would be causing this. I've tried searching my whole project and commenting out all `<service>` tags and the duplicate, empty service still persists. This is a problem because my app direct's users to turn the service on, but there's always two services that appear identical, and only one of them works for enabling my accessibility functionality. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out one of the dependencies included in my project was binding to an accessibility service. The solution is to either remove the dependency, or edit the dependency if you are the author and do not wish to use the accessibility service there.